# Apache won't start ubuntu

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu

When I'm running `service apache2 start`
I get the response

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
```

When running `netstat -tulpn| grep :80

I get the response.

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run this command with admin permissions. Call `sudo service apache2 start`.

And if this doesn't help. Go for `su` and after successfull login run your command. It should work this time.